# Require the same file on multiple instances

Tags: php, sql

I'm doing a simple login and register kinda of site, and I came accross a multiple access to a file problem. I keep the db connection on a file and I am requiring it anytime I need to access the db. The problem is that I now started to clean the code and transfer some similar blocks of code to functions and the problem is I ended up with something like this:

```
<? php
     function one()
     {
           require 'connection.file.php';
           (...)
           return $result;
     }
     function two()
     {
           require 'connection.file.php';
           (...)
           $varible = one();
     }
```

I didn't quite understand the whole include/require aspect of php, is there a way I can, when I call these two functions, pass the required files, so I don't need to include them everytime?

EDIT: Managed to correct this. Like the answers say, the require needs to be global, however my connection variable must be also declared as global. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: What in the world...

Comment: That's exatly my thoughts on require/include

Comment: require 'connection.file.php';
function one() { (...) return $result; }
function two() { (...) $varible = one(); }

Comment: bad-ish idea. you'd be connecting to the db on every function call, and disconnecting when the function exits,b ecause PHP will clean up any local variables defined/used in the function, including your database handle.

Comment: It's a really bad idea, because I knew I would come to this point, however, I tried to require before the functions and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Require/include it globally instead:

```
<?php
require 'connection.file.php';
function one()
{
      //(...)
      return $result;
}
function two()
{
      //(...)
      $varible = one();
}
// ...
```

Comment: I've tried that, but I get an error saying that it can't connect.

Comment: That's an entirely separate question. You asked how to require the same file for each function.

Comment: For me its kinda the same, because it should work like you said, exept it doesn't.

Comment: For that reason, you should ask a more specific question. Myself as well as @JonStory gave you the answer to *this* question specifically. Anything else is beyond the scope of this particular question and should be placed into an entirely new one.

Comment: Yeah I was about 20 seconds behind you on the answer :) but I agree, you appear to have an issue with your connectivity which requires a second question. When making the new question, remember to include code snippets, the error you see, and make sure you remove your SQL password from the code snippet!

Comment: Will do. I'm also coding on a localhost, so it's no problem. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Alright guys, managed to do it. The global require works, but I need to make the connection query variable (not really sure whats its definition) global as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Put the require at the top of your code, not inside the function.

I'd recommend using require_once for most things, too, as it avoids accidentally re-declaring functions. Only use include/require instead of include_once/require_once if you know you'll need the file more than once.

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.file.php';

function one()
{
    //stuff
}

function two()
{
    //other stuff
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include the other .php file at the top. See the code below for more 
explanation:

The advantage of one requiring is that it is more performant 
(your server doesn't have to load the other file 2 times)

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.file.php';

function firstFunction()
{
    //first stuff
}

function secondFunction()
{
    //other stuff
}
?> code here
```